# How to mock a method returning Task<IEnumerable<T>> with Task<List<T>>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm attempting to set up a unit test initializer (in Moq) where an interface method is being mocked:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<myCustomObject>> GetSomethingAsync(string someStringParam);
}

...

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    var repoMock = new Mock<IRepository>();

    var objectsList = new List<myCustomObject>() {
        new myCustomObject("Something"), 
        new myCustomObject("Otherthing")
    }

    repoMock.Setup<Task<IEnumerable<myCustomObject>>>(
        rep => rep.GetSomethingAsync("ThisParam")
    ).Returns(Task.FromResult(objectsList)); //error here
}
```

The issue I'm having is I can't figure out how to get the method to return my `objectsList`. In practice this of course works fine because List implements IEnumerable, but it doesn't seem to work when wrapped in a Task, in Moq. The error I get is on the `Returns()` method:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<
  System.Collections.Generic.List<myCustomObject>>'
to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<
  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<myCustomObject>>'
```

As a workaround I *can* create another method that simply creates the `List<myObj>` and returns it as `IEnumerable<myObj>`, but I feel like there must be another way to handle this that is cleaner.

So, how would I do this without having to create the helper method?

Comment: What if instead of using `var` you did `IEnumerable<myCustomObject> objectsList = new List<myCustomObject>()`?

Comment: Just because two types `A` and `B` exhibit a particular inheritance/implementation relationship, that does *not* mean that `G<A>` and `G<B>` exhibit the *same* relationship.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to specify the `<IEnumerable<myCustomObject>>` on the `Task.FromResult`, like this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    var repoMock = new Mock<IRepository>();

    var objectsList = new List<myCustomObject>() {
        new myCustomObject("Something"), 
        new myCustomObject("Otherthing")
    }

    repoMock.Setup<Task<IEnumerable<myCustomObject>>>(
        rep => rep.GetSomethingAsync("ThisParam")
    ).Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<myCustomObject>>(objectsList));
}
```

Alternatively you could declare your `objectList` as `<IEnumerable<myCustomObject>>` before assigning it from the `List<myCustomObject>`. Making the previous suggestion not required.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I had tried using the ```Returns<T>```, but I hadn't considered ```FromResult<T>```. The latter suggestion is similar to my workaround and while it works, I was looking for how to do it in-line. I just couldn't quite wrap my head around it. Thanks you!

Answer (score 7):

You could generically cast your original object:

```
IEnumerable<myCustomObject> objectsList = new List<myCustomObject>() {
    new myCustomObject("Something"), 
    new myCustomObject("Otherthing")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ReturnsAsync instead of Returns when mocking the method.

```
repoMock.Setup<Task<IEnumerable<myCustomObject>>>(
    rep => rep.GetSomethingAsync("ThisParam")
).ReturnsAsync(objectsList);
```